# Prove if $f\colon X\to \mathbb R$, $X ⊂ \mathbb R$ is continuous, then $g(x) :=|f(x)|$, $g\colon X\to\mathbb R$ is also continuous

Tags: calculus, continuity

How can I prove that if $f\colon X\to \mathbb R$, $X ⊂ \mathbb R$ is continuous, then $g(x) :=|f(x)|$, $g\colon X\to\mathbb R$ is also continuous?

I tried coming up with a function that respects the stated value, but that didn't help me solve it. Any ideas?

EDIT: I am also curious to know how would I prove that the reverse of that statement is not always valid? So if g is continous, then f is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It follows from the inequality $| |a|-|b| | \leq |a-b|$ valid for any two real numbers. Thus if you have for given $\epsilon >0$ that $\delta$ is good for the definition of continuity of $f$, the same $\delta$ is good for $g$. Another way to see this is that $g$ is a composition of two continuous functions, $f$ and $h(x):=|x|$.

Comment: Much better answer than mine!

Comment: Oh, I see. But how would I prove that the reverse of that statement is not always valid? So if g is continous, then f is not.

Comment: Consider for example $f(x)=1$ for $x \geq 0$ and $f(x)=-1$ for $x<0$. Then $f$ is not continuous but $|f|$ is constant so continuous

Answer (score 1):

The reverse triangle inequality implies that
$$
||f(x)|-|f(y)||\leq |f(x)-f(y)|
$$
for all $x,y.$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\operatorname{abs}(x)=|x|$. Then $g=\operatorname{abs}\circ f$. Since it is the composition of two continuous functions, $g$ is continuous too.

On the other hand, suppose that$$f(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }x\in\mathbb Q\\-1&\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$(I am assuming that $U=\mathbb R$ here). Then $g=|f|\equiv1$ is continuous, but $f$ is discontinuous everywhere.

Comment: But how would I prove that the reverse of that statement is not always valid? So if g is continous, then f is not.

Comment: @MathHawk That is a new question. Please post it as such.

Comment: I added the question into the main question as an edit. Is that ok?

Comment: @MathHawk I've edited my answer, but it would have been better if you had posted it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: you only need to show that $g$ is continuous at its roots, since it's certainly continuous away from its roots. Indeed, by the intermediate value theorem, for every $x$ where $f(x) \not = 0$ there is a ball around $x$ where $f$ takes the same sign on that entire ball, and hence where $g$ is defined either as the continuous $f$ or the continuous $-f$.